# I want to condense a list of ranges (from-to)

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have data involving codes assigned to ranges in the form of

```
From   To     Code
0      5      A
5      10     A
10     15     A
15     20     B
20     25     B
25     30     A
30     35     A
35     40     A
40     45     C
45     50     C
50     55     C
55     60     B
60     65     B
65     70     B
```

I want to condense this list to a list like this

```
From   To     Code
0      15     A
15     25     B
25     40     A
40     55     C
55     70     B
```

where contiguous ranges (e.g., 0-5, 5-10, and 10-15) with the same code are merged.
I am wondering if this could be done by `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: Actually the data is supposed to be a table with three columns From To and Code.  Apparently I do not know how to format that in my question and ended up with everything on one row by mistake.

Comment: I assume your ranges are guaranteed to be sorted. Are they guaranteed to be contiguous, or can there be gaps (e.g., `25 30 A` followed by `35 40 A`, skipping 30-35)?

Answer (score 2):

It can be easy done by `awk`

```
awk '
    NR==1{
        print
        next }
    f!=$3{
        if(NR!=2)
            print(line)
        printf("%s\t",$1)
        f=$3 }
    {
        line=$2 "\t" $3 }
    END{
        print line }
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using full text substitutions:

```
perl -p0E 'while( s/\n(\d+\s+)(\d+)\s+(\w+)\n\2\s+(\d+\s+\3)/\n$1$4/ ){}'
```

or with comments and indentation...

```
perl -p0E 'while(                        # while we can
  s/\n                                      # substitute
    (\d+  \s+)   (\d+)  \s+     (\w+)  \n     # n1 n2 id
     \2   \s+    (\d+   \s+      \3 )         # n2 n3 id    by
   /\n$1$4/x                                  # n1 n3 id
){}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data are always in order (as you presented) then you can simply parse rows finding the first and last row in a "group" where the code is the same. For each group, save the "from" value for the first row and the "to" value for the final row (before the code changes). Print those groups using the values you've saved.

Comment: Okay.  I realize that but I just do not know how to go about coding the procedure.